# Task.Factory.StartNew duplication issue

Tags: c#, task, taskfactory

The following code produces an event log of 14, 15, 16, 16 when I expect 13, 14, 15, 16, i.e. each number to be written to event log once, regardless of order.

The question is why is it missing 13 and duplicating 16?

```
List<int> webReports = new List<int>{13,14,15,16};

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (int webReportNo in webReports)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoStuff(webReportNo)));
}

private static void DoStuff(int webReportNo)
{
    //Write webReportNo to event log.
}
```

Comment: This works fine for me, perhaps it's something to do with closures. What version of compiler are you using here?

Comment: Presumably you're using c# 4.0 compiler or lower. Closing over the loop issue is fixed in c# 5.0

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: as far as I understand, in case of 4.0 OP should get 13, 13, 13, 13 in the log. Isn't it?

Comment: @Dennis No. That depends on when `StartNew` is executed. If it executes delayed, he'll get 16, 16, 16... otherwise some unpredictable values depending on thread scheduling and threadpool resources at the time.

Comment: Ah you beauties!... it was the modified closure problem, I was aware of it for linq to entities, but didn't think it was an issue with Tasks... THANKS!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: yep, I've confused with last value.

Comment: P.S. You were correct that I am using C# 4.0 released with .NET 4 and VS2010 (Runtime v4.0.30319)